# How to set the user permission on MSMQ queue creation in Wix

Tags: wix, msmq, wix3.5, user-permissions

As part of a Wix installation I'm trying to create an MSMQ private queue using the MsmqExtension:

```
<msmq:MessageQueue Id='myQueue' Label='My Queue' Transactional='yes' PathName='[MESSAGE_QUEUE_NAME]'/>
```

As the windows service I'm installing is running under a different user to that which is performing the install I'm not sure that it will be able to read and write to this private queue and the extensions schema doesn't give the option to set specific users. Is there a way round this or would I have to implement the queue creation as a custom action to have this flexibility?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [MessageQueuePermission](http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix3/msmq_xsd_messagequeuepermission.htm) element to achieve this.